# The equation of the line pass through $2$ points in $3D$ space.

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a line equation passes through $2$ points in a $3$-dimensional space, and use it to determine the intersection between sphere and line.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the formula of a line equation through 2 points in a 2-dimensional space ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's an equation

Comment: I know how to find the equation of a line in 2D space but not in 3D.Can you help?

Comment: perhaps . . . . What's the **equation** of a line equation through 2 points in a 2-dimensional space ?

Comment: Sorry about typos, I fixed it

Comment: What is straight line intersection with the sphere? Do you mean the intersection between sphere and line?

Comment: I just use that equation to determine the straight line intersects the sphere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With points $A(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $B(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, the **canonical** equation of a line that passes through these points is
$$\dfrac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}=\dfrac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_1-z_0}$$
One may take this equal to parameter $t\in\mathbb{R}$ to use the **parametric** equation of that line, which is
$$
\begin{cases}
x=(x_1-x_0)t+x_0,\\
y=(y_1-y_0)t+y_0,\\
z=(z_1-z_0)t+z_0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can you give me an example or site link for this?

Comment: Which of these two equations is used to find the intersection?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx

Comment: parameteric equation is good for your work

Comment: thank for help,i will try ^^

Comment: also https://www.vitutor.com/geometry/space/line_space.html sounds good .

Comment: you are welcome.